# Teradata - How to group data within a time period

Tags: sql, teradata

I have some data records in Teradata generated by a transaction system in the following format:

```
EVENT_ID      CUSTOMER      EVENT_CODE     EVENT_DATE       EVENT_TIME
123456        100           A01            24/09/2021       09:05:02
123457        100           Z99            24/09/2021       09:05:02
123458        100           A01            24/09/2021       09:05:02
123459        100           A01            24/09/2021       09:05:03
```

The system unfortunately sometimes creates multiple records for the same transaction. In the above example, there was 1 transaction processed but multiple "A01" event records created.

I'm wanting to select the minimum EVENT_ID value for "A01" grouped on CUSTOMER, EVENT_CODE, EVENT_DATE and where the EVENT_TIME is within 5 seconds of each other.

If I run the following it will output EVENT_IDs 123456 and 123459 because the latter is 1 second different. I only want it to output 123456 though because the other "A01" events are within 5 seconds.

```
SELECT MIN(EVENT_ID),
       CUSTOMER,
       EVENT_DATE,
       EVENT_TIME
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE EVENT_CODE = 'A01'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER,
         EVENT_DATE,
         EVENT_TIME
```

Comment: *within 5 seconds*: What result do you want for 09:05:02 #1, 09:05:06 #2, 09:05:10 #3? Both #2 & #3 are within 5 seconds after the previous, but #3 is 8 seconds after #1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a threshold with `lag()`.  I'm not sure what threshold you want, but here is a 5 second threshold:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
qualify event_time > lag(event_time) over (partition by customer, event_code, event_date order by event_time) - interval '5' second;
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried this but it's outputting 100% of the records unfortunately. I've extracted every "A01" event out of the table as the original is huge so it was running quite slow. My new table structure is the same as my original post just without the EVENT_CODE.

We actually want it to group on a 10 minute threshold so we ran:

`select *
from mytable
qualify event_time < lead(event_time, 1, event_time + interval '10' minute) over (partition by customer, event_date order by event_time) + interval '10' minute`

Your code had a 10 and 5 second interval -was that a typo/significant?

Comment: @markthornton90 . . . I think I had the logic backwards.  You want the events where the previous event has some noticeable gap -- that is, look backwards not forwards.